# Passing connection string to Entity framework at runt time for each call

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, connection-string, autofac

My Entity framework context is as following

```
 public partial class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public MyContext()
        : base("Name=MyContext")
    {
    }
```

I am resolving it through autofac in the following way

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(MainContext)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MainContext>().As<IMainContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

This db context gets called in repository layer

```
#region Fields

    private readonly IMyContext _context;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public EmployeeRepository(IMyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    #endregion

    public void Create(Employee emp)
    {
        this._context.Employee.Add(emp);
    }
```

Now my issue is , I want to set the connection string dynamically per call. The connection string will be passed through a webapi which i want to pass on to this context. Can anyone help me how can i do that? I am confused about autofac here. Secondly how can i make sure each call sets connection string and does not cache it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a factory that will build the context and set the connectionstring for you.

```
public interface IContextFactory
{
    IContext GetInstance();
}

public class MyContextFactory : IContextFactory 
{
    public IContext GetInstance()      
    {
        String connectionString = this.GetConnectionString(HttpContext.Current); 
        return new MyContext(connectionString); 
    }

    private String GetConnectionString(HttpContext context)
    {
        // do what you want
    }
}


builder.RegisterType<MyContextFactory>()
       .As<IContextFactory>()
       .InstancePerRequest(); 
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IContextFactory>().GetInstance())
       .As<IContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

If you can't get connectionstring based on HttpContext, you can change contextFactory implementation to expect initialization by WebAPI before creating the instance. For example :

```
public interface IContextFactory
{
    IContext GetInstance();
    void Initialize(String connectionString);
}

public class MyContextFactory : IContextFactory 
{

    private String _connectionString; 

    public void Initialize(String connectionString)
    {
        this._connectionString = connectionString; 
    }

    public IContext GetInstance()      
    {
        if (this._connectionString == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("connectionString not initialized"); 
        }
        return new MyContext(this._connectionString); 
    }
}
```

At the beginning of your web API call (through attribute for example), you can call the `Initialize` method. Because the factory is `InstancePerRequest` you will have one instance for the duration of the request.

---

By the way, I'm not sure to understand this registration

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(MainContext)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<MainContext>().As<IMainContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

It looks buggy because you will have 2 different registration of the same type and not for the same scope, is it intended ? Furthermore, it doesn't sound a good idea to register a `DbContext`, do you need this registration ?

The following registration looks better :

```
builder.RegisterType<MainContext>()
       .As<IMainContext>()
       .As<DbContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Can we chat to discuss this?

Comment: Do i need to inject Context Factory whereever i am using Context. The trouble is i am using context in Repositoty and Unit of Work both. I can send you code sample?